# Twitter Widget on Blogger

Tags: html, layout, twitter, blogger

How can I fix the view of this twitter on my blogger blog.

Here it is the widget page:
http://twitter.com/goodies/widget_profile

Here it is how it ends looking on the blog (not rounded corners, misplaced names and images):
http://my2hours.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your widget's css file is not pulling through.
You could try adding

```
<link href="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/1/widget.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

in the head section of your site.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing some of the code they give you. You need to have the line with widget.css to get the styling.